# Am I blocked on messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am not blocked on FB because I can still see the account. When I click on the chat on messenger, I can still see profile picture but phone and video icons are gone. I also can’t see the “view their profile” option. Am I blocked on messenger?